# Google Maps Matrix API returning status:ZERO_RESULTS UK postcodes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the maps matrix api to find the transit distances between locations in England.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
units=metric
&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
&origins=SE108aJ
&destinations=SE164UN
&mode=transit
&arrival_time=1568618400
&region=UK
```

It returns:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "London SE16 4UN, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Dartmouth Hill, Blackheath, London SE10 8AJ, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The same request to Google maps works:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/SE10+8AJ,+Dartmouth+Hill,+Blackheath,+London/London+SE16+4UN

So I'm a little confused why the API call doesn't

Comment: Probably has to do with `mode=transit` and `arrival_time=1568618400`

Comment: If I put 9/16/2019 7:20 am in [the linked map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/SE10+8AJ,+Dartmouth+Hill,+Blackheath,+London/London+SE16+4UN), [I don't get results](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Dartmouth+Hill,+London+SE10+8AJ,+UK/SE16+4UN,+London,+UK/@51.4854952,-0.0550396,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x4876027d9bcc5097:0x5c050a2ab2be45ed!2m2!1d-0.0084909!2d51.4720539!1m5!1m1!1s0x48760338ddceba9d:0xd46fea63b230df5c!2m2!1d-0.0679181!2d51.5002881!2m3!6e1!7e2!8j1568618400!3e3) (it says "Sorry, we could not calculate transit directions...").

Comment: I think I've replied to you twice, but my comments keep disappearing?! Thanks, the issue was with the date and I've added an answer belwo. I couldn't find that explanation in the API. Any idea why people are downvoting the question? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I had included an arrival time that is in the past, changing this to a future time and date allowed it to work.

2019-09-16 08:20:00 GMT  ==    1568618400

NOW == 1573060070

2019-11-16 08:20:00 GMT  ==    1573892400

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
units=metric
&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
&origins=SE108aJ
&destinations=SE164UN
&mode=transit
&arrival_time=1573892400
&region=UK
```

results in:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "London SE16 4UN, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Dartmouth Hill, Blackheath, London SE10 8AJ, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "9.1 km",
                  "value" : 9143
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "41 mins",
                  "value" : 2481
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```